# NoMethodError when trying to get data from two models on one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

OK, I am new to rails but trying to learn so my apologies if this question exposes my lack of knowledge!

I have a very simple application with 2 models (Building & Customise) and 2 Controllers (Buildings & Customises) each with an index view.

My root is buildings#index

Within buildings#index view I am trying to access data from both models along the lines of:

```
    <div class="wrap">
            <header>

                <% @setup.each do |customise| %>

                <h1><%= customise.title %></h1>

                <% end %>
```

Where in my buildings controller I have defined:

```
    def index

@buildings = Building.all
@unis = Building.where(buildingtype: "uni")

if params[:parentd].present?
@buildings = Building.where("university = ? OR buildingtype = 'directlet'", params[:parentd])

@setup = Customise.all

end
```

This yields the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
4:  
5: <% end %>
6: 
7: <% @unis.each do |uni| %>
8: <option value="<%= uni.name %>"><%= uni.name %></option>
9: <% end %>
app/views/customises/index.html.erb:7:in 
  `_app_views_customises_index_html_erb__589235851577785880_2190604320'
```

My reading suggests that accessing data from two models in any view is possible which led me to believe that there is something wrong with my notation.

However, when I try to access the same model information, in the same way but within a view associated with the customises controller the data shows without error.

Can anybody suggest the reason behind this?

Comment: i think in your controller the if condition does not getting satisfied so @setup is nil

Comment: Thank you. I stupidly didn't notice that it was within the IF statement! Many thanks

Comment: can i put that as answer so you can accept that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, the if condition is not getting satisfied, so `@setup` is `nil`. Make sure `@setup` gets initialized.

Answer (score 3):

Is your `Customise Model` contains any data? If yes then please check your condition that is

```
if params[:parentd].present?
```

you are not getting your `params` that is `[:parentd]`

Answer (score 0):

The error **undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass** indicates that you have tried to call method #each on nil class's instance

In your case `@unis` is `nil` (from the log you provided).

You can either make sure that `@unit` is never `nil` in controller.
Or try to put in it in **if..else** block in your view.

For example:

```
<% if @unit.nil? %>
  <%# Show message regarding nil value of @unit %>
<% else %>
  <%# Your normal logic of showing @unit %>
<% end %>
```